# Blender won't import .3ds file despite working in Photoshop

Tags: python, import, error

I am trying to import a .3ds file into Blender, but I am getting the following error:

[image: Report: Error]

The .3ds file in question was produced by an extraction/conversion script from a different convoluted file format, so I assume this is where the issue lies. However, the file imports fine into Photoshop, of all things.

I have tried exporting to OBJ from Photoshop, but the file is empty upon import (no vertices, objects, etc.)

I have tried opening the .3ds file in Maya and 3DS Max (specifically Maya 2014 and 3DSM 2015, which I read should have worked), no luck there either (it says improper file format).

I have also tried Autodesk's FBX Converter, which seems to be mildly better except all the vertices are collapsed together (there are 1K vertices in the file but they're all at 0,0,0.) I don't know if this is an issue on Blender's end or the converter's end.

I have also tried a really old version of Blender (can't remember which specifically at the moment), no luck there either (although I did read that this was supposed to work, but no.)

I recognize that in all likelihood this is not an issue with Blender, but the details in the error message made me think maybe someone here would know what I can do to further troubleshoot.

Oh one more detail, I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the file does not include a mesh but instead a bunch of unconnected vertices (a vertex cloud). If any programming savvy people here would know how to simply output the vertex coordinates so it can be read that way, that would work just as well.

[Here is an example of a .3ds file (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_nHzAY7Z18VTd6ZGNmaXN0ZFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't think .3ds format is good choice here as it has some limitations like [vertices pre mesh count or triangle mesh limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds). If none of programs imports it as expected then most likely there isn't what you're searching for. If possible export to another format for point clouds

Comment: @MrZak I wish I could. The problem is, .3ds is the only feasible output format for the script that was used to extract/convert the original data. Normally I would chalk it up as simply a bad file format, except, like I said, it does actually work in Photoshop, and there is also a conversion application that works for some people. So I know it's possible to get the data out of the file, and since Blender does actually give a comprehensive error message, I would think that information could be used to troubleshoot the issue, though I could be wrong.

Comment: There was [similar error](https://developer.blender.org/T45516) while importing before but not .3ds rather than .fbx. I don't have idea about what's going on with this file which opens in one app and doesn't in others. Try filing bug report at https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1, maybe it's really bug (make sure to check latest Blender versions first)

Comment: Jace, can you please describe a full path from creation/download of the mesh and which software and formats were used. And, if possible, provide a mesh in another format.

Comment: @martinsifrar I didn't do this myself, someone else did and handed over the .3ds files, so my technical knowledge of this is limited. However, I do happen to know the process.

First we ripped .GO files (model file format) off of a video game disc (Jak and Daxter: The Precursor Legacy, if that's relevant), and used a BMS script ([this one](https://ps23dformat.wikispaces.com/file/view/JAKtest2.bms)) to convert it into a readable format (.3ds). We used QuickBMS to do this. The guy behind the magic describes his process [here](http://ps23dformat.wikispaces.com/How+To+Extract+Models).

Comment: Oh, I might need to add, I think .GO files are container files for multiple files IIRC.

Comment: I am not in any way qualified to talk about this script, but would it be possible to maybe convert  .GO into something more suitable for point clouds, for example, .PLY?

Comment: @martinsifrar Actually I was able to convert the 3DS files into PLY, as you suggested, using a program called 3D Object Converter, which for some odd reason was able to open the 3DS file, similar to Photoshop. The PLY files import to Blender perfectly. If you would like to post an answer recommending the PLY format I'd be happy to accept/award the bounty. Otherwise if this question needs to be closed as off-topic, I understand.

Comment: photoshop is known to me for notoriously exporting bad 3d formats. especially obj. try to avoid it

Comment: Super MegaBroBro posted this solution as an answer. You can give the bounty to him and mark it as a valid answer so this thread can be closed. Anyways, glad you did it and hope I helped at least a bit.

Comment: Do you have the source files? (whatever the format)

Comment: Very interesting read about the 3DS file format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds

In human terms: it's hard to read the file manually because it's a binary. Still gonna try to read it though... Not sure I'm gonna get lucky however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user: martinsifrar suggests. You might be able to convert to the PLY format instead of the GO format. It appears you can use software called 3D Object Converter to accomplish this :)

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

what i think is that its not the issue of blender or max or maya.... the extraction conversation step has resulted in a corrupted file... which however photoshop is able to read(given that photshop is not meant for 3d)...if you have windows 10... try opening it in window 3d viewer and if it is viewable there.. export it in obj format

Comment: Unfortunately it is not viewable in Windows 3D viewer. I do not think it's a corrupt file, as converting it to PLY format allows Blender to import it properly. I think Photoshop is able to import the original .3ds file format because it might support older formats due to a lack of updates, because, like you said, it is not a 3D-first program.